# C# allowed values attribute

Tags: c#

I have a Variable and I want to allow only certain values in it.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Category must be provided")]
[Range(2, 4)]
public int Category { get; set; }
```

I want to allow some more values in that variable lets say 6 and 10. How should I do it? Is there a attribute where I can specify specific values I allow?

Comment: Why is `Category` an `int`? Why not an `enum`?

Comment: Because I want the user to enter only int values.

Comment: Why not use js validation

Comment: Because you should always do server-side validation @lostmylogin

Comment: Could you please add some context for this question.

Comment: Who can assign this value and how? Is it a class that's programmed against by others, or do you use this in a web context? How do you want to check and deny out-of-range values? Attributes in and of themselves do nothing, but MVC and Web API have built-in validation. Or do you want to validate in the setter?

Comment: You have not tagged your question with any technology that would allow this. As your question stands, the only answer is "This cannot be done without external tools". Did you mean to tag it [ASP.NET] or maybe [PostSharp]?

Comment: I have decided to use Enums, thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**

Use JavaScript validation either on form submit handler or key up/down handler

**Option 2**

Use RegularExpression data annotation like this

```
[RegularExpression("[2|6]", ErrorMessage = "Enter 2 or 6 only")]
```

**Option 3**

Use custom validators

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom validation attribute. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;    

namespace MyProject.Models.Validation
{

    public class SpecialCategoryAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if(value == 6 || value == 10)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }


            return new ValidationResult("Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that there is a conflict between the attribute: `Range` allow 2->4 and `SpecialCategory` allows only 6 and 10. So, your model isn't valid always.

I think you can remove your `Range` and use only `SpecialCategory` with the values 2->4 and 6 and 10 alowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
[RegularExpression("[2|4|6|10]")]
public int Category { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[RegularExpression("^(2|4|6|10)$")]
public int Category { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you mean [RegularExpression("^(2|3|4|6|10)$")]

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET 8.0 you can use `AllowedValues` and `DeniedValues` attributes.

For example: `[AllowedValues(2,3,4)]`

[Read more about `AllowedValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.allowedvaluesattribute?view=net-8.0)

[Read more about `DeniedValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.deniedvaluesattribute?view=net-8.0)